# LINQ: How to return all child elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

For an application I am working on, I have to display data from an XML File. There's a few transformations being done, but eventually the end result will be displayed in a treeview. When a user then clicks on a node, I want to pop up the details in a listview.

When no node has been selected, I basically use LINQ to grab the details of the first item I encounter.

Here's a simplified version of my XML

```
<root>
   <parent label="parent1">
      <child label="child1">
         <element1>data</element1>
         <element2>data</element2>
         ...
      </child>
      <child label="child2">
         <element1>data</element1>
         <element2>data</element2>
         ...
      </child>
   </parent>
</root>
```

And here's the code used to grab it (After selecting the parent-node that the treeview has been set to by means of an XPAthSelectStatement):

```
protected void listsSource_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(MapPath(TreeSource.DataFile));
    rootElement = rootElement.XPathSelectElement("//parent[@label='parent1']");
    XElement parentElement;

    parentElement = rootElement;

    var query = (from itemElement in parentElement.Descendants("child")
                 select new
                 {
                     varElement1 = itemElement.Element("element1").Value,
                     varElement2 = itemElement.Element("element2").Value,
                     ...
                 }).Take(1);

    e.result = Query;
}
```

This works a treat, and I can read out the `varElement1` and `varElement2` values from there. However, when I try and implement a similar mechanism for when the user actually did select a node, I seem to run into a wall.

My approach was to use another `XPatchSelectStatement` to get to the actual node:

```
parentElement = rootElement.XPathSelectElement("//child[@label='" + tvwChildren.SelectedNode.Text + "']");
```

But I am kind of stumped on how to now get a proper LINQ query built up to read in all elements nested under the child node. I tried using `parentElement.Elements()`, but that was yielding an error. I also looked at using `Nodes()`, but with similar results.

I suppose I could use a foreach loop to access the nodes, but then I'm not sure how to get the results into a LINQ query so I can return the same `e.Result = query` back.

I'm fairly new to LINQ, as you might have guessed, so any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I actually managed to figure out that I simply could use:

var query = (from itemElement in parentElement.DescendantsAndSelf("child")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query that will give you the child element (given that there is only one `child` element with the specified label):

```
var childElement = rootNode.Descendants("child")
                           .Single(e=>e.Attribute("label").Value == "child1");
```

If you have more than one `child` elements with `label="child1"` but those elements are under different `parent` elements you can use the same approach to get first the `parent` element and then the `child` element.

Having the above, you can use this query to get all `element` nodes under the `child` node:

```
var elements = childElement.Descendants().Select(e=>e.Value);
```

Comment: The second snippet seems to do what I was/am after. I can see the values in the query result. I'll play around and see how I can now load the values from there into the varElement1 and varElement2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think data binding is much easier in this case.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
if (doc.Root == null)
{
throw new ApplicationException("invalid data");
}
tvwChildren.Source=doc;
```

But if you want in this way hope following one helps(not the exact solution)

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("Employees.xml");
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(root.Name.LocalName);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
    foreach(XElement employee in root.Elements())
           {
            TreeNode employeeNode = new TreeNode("Employee ID :" + employee.Attribute("employeeid").Value);
            rootNode.Nodes.Add(employeeNode);
                 if (employee.HasElements)
                 {
                    foreach(XElement employeechild in employee.Descendants())
                     {
                        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(employeechild.Value);
                        employeeNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                     }
                 }
            }
```

And you can try Resharper tool for create better linq statements. It shows possible ones and you can easily convert each for,foreach loops into linq statements.

Comment: While I'm not sure your method would work for my needs (I have the treeview working, but am now trying to read things out from there into my listview), I really appreciate the tip about Resharper. I'll go give that a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like it could be this:

```
var data =
    from p in xml.Root.Elements("parent")
    where p.Attribute("label").Value == "parent1"
    from c in p.Elements("child")
    where c.Attribute("label").Value == "child2"
    from d in c.Elements()
    select d.Value;
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this Xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) you can write your XPath like:

```
XElement child = rootElement.XPathElement(
    "//parent[@label={0}]/child[@label={1}]", "parent1", "child2");
```